# Having problems with assert in c

Tags: c, assert

I'm working on a programming assignment at the moment where the objective is to compare hashing strategies. For the main part of the program, the user is allowed to use it with options (using getopt).
The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have an option that tells the program to scan through a dictionary and compares words given in from stdin with the words in the dictionary, and prints the words with differences (words from stdin). Here is a code partial:

```
if (flag_c) {

while (getword(word, sizeof word, fopen(filename, "r")) != EOF) {
  start = clock();
  if (htable_search(h, word) == 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", word);
    unknown_word_count++;
  }
  search_time += (clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

printf("Fill time     : %f\n", fill_time);
printf("Search time   : %f\n", search_time);
printf("Unknown words = %d\n", unknown_word_count);
```

}

Now I think the problem lies in the while loop conditon. The getword function is defined below:

```
int getword(char *s, int limit, FILE *stream) {
  int c;
  char *w = s;
  assert(limit > 0 && s != NULL && stream != NULL);



/* skip to the start of the word */
while (!isalnum(c = getc(stream)) && EOF != c)
    ;
  if (EOF == c) {
    return EOF;
  } else if (--limit > 0) { /* reduce limit by 1 to allow for the \0 */
    *w++ = tolower(c);
  }
  while (--limit > 0) {
    if (isalnum(c = getc(stream))) {
      *w++ = tolower(c);
    } else if ('\'' == c) {
      limit++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  *w = '\0';
  return w - s;
}
```

When I run the program I get the error:

```
Test: mylib.c:10: getword: Assertion `limit > 0 && s != ((void *)0) && stream != ((void *)0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm really not too sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` then learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

Comment: I'm guessing that eventually `fopen` fails when the system runs out of file handles, thus triggering the assert condition `stream != NULL`.  To confirm this you could split your assert into three different tests.

Comment: Also, since you read a new file stream each iteration, you will get the same word each time.  Open the file once, and save the value in a variable, and test the the open succeeded.  Then pass the variable to the function, and close the (single) file after the loop.

Comment: Next time you hit a similar issue: Instead of one assert with three conditions, if you use three asserts with one condition each, it will be a lot easier to see, because you'll know which one went bad. In other words, break it into: `assert(limit > 0);`, `assert(s != NULL);` and `assert(stream != NULL);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `fopen` in the while loop:

```
while (getword(word, sizeof word, fopen(filename, "r")) != EOF) {
```

Does `getword` close the `FILE*`? If not you have a lot of open file handles.

What you probably need is:

1. Open the file before the start of the `while` loop.
2. Use the `FILE*` in the loop.
3. Close the file after you get out of the `while` loop.

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if ( fp == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error condition.
}

while (getword(word, sizeof word, fp) != EOF) {
  start = clock();
  if (htable_search(h, word) == 0) {

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", word);
    unknown_word_count++;
  }
  search_time += (clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

fclose(fp);
```